# How I can disable login page for users who logged in already

Tags: php, mysql

How I can disable login page for users who logged in already? 
I tried a lot to writing php code for "if user logged in already can't logged in again and can't see login page" but I didn't know

```
<?php
    session_start(); 

    if(isset($_SESSION['user_name'])) 
    { 
        header('Location: home.php'); 
        exit;
    }
?>
```

Comment: you need to post some code. show us what you tried

Comment: where do you set the `$_SESSION['user_name']` variable?  If you don't set it, it's never going to get into that if condition.

Comment: Are you setting your session variable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should take a look at this post: [Using sessions & session variables in a PHP Login Script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10097887/using-sessions-session-variables-in-a-php-login-script). Here you can see how to use php session for the same use case!

Answer (score 2):

create session .if session set then redirect to page in the header location

```
<?php  

  session_start();  // needed for sessions.
    if(isset($_SESSION['url'])) 
       $url = $_SESSION['url']; // holds url for last page visited.
    else 
       $url = "index.php"; // default page for 

    header("Location: http://example.com/$url");//redirect page you want
```