# Usage of Session in PHP when coming back from some other page

Tags: php, session, post

I have a login page where the user has to provide his/her credentials and then log in to the page named *dashboard.php*.

Now the credential validation is done on this page.I used **$_POST** to pass the variables. If user credentials are not correct then he is taken back to *index.php*.
Else the page is filled with user data from the db.

Now the problem is that when user revists *dashboard.php* from any other page (other than *index.php*) How do I get the same credentials back so as to show the contents related to the user?
I tried using session variables by saving the credentials in them but still not working.

I have added a sample code of what I have done:

index.php

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form action="dashboard.php" method="post">
        <input type="text" name="txt">
        <input type="submit">
    </form>
</body>
```

this travels to dashboard.php which is:

```
<?php
    session_start();
   if(isset($_SESSION['LOG_IN'])!=1)
{

    $xt = $_POST['txt'];
    $_SESSION['LOG_IN']=1;

}

?>

<html>
    <head>

    </head>
    <body>
        <p> HI </p>
        <a href="3.php"><?php $xt ?>Link of 3.php</a>

    </body>
</html>
```

and now when i go to some page called 3.php and press the back button. I get the form re-submission page.

Comment: The idea is to set your session variables once the user has logged in. At the `dashboard.php` you check if the session variable for logged in is `true`, if not then redirect to `index.php`. On logout, destroy the session.

Comment: What you want to achieve is the basic of PHP session, get a basic PHP book or check the manual [Session Handling](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.session.php)

Comment: you have not started session on the first line of dashboard page

Comment: even after doing that it is not working. Whenever I come back to the page it asks for form resubmission

Comment: after session_start() please print_r your $_POST. As I think you are checking isset($_SESSION['LOG_IN']) before defining.

Comment: Thats the point of isset() to check if it exists or not. Right?

Comment: First of all you have to set session variable i.e $_SESSION['LOG_IN']=1; then you can access it or check it anywhere. What you actually want then I can write answer acc. to it.

Answer (score 0):

To make SESSION work on every page you must use `session_start();` on each page at the top of page.

Then you can easily access session using `print_r($_SESSION);`

You should refer to [PHP Session Documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.session.php) for more info.

You should use session_start(); at top of page. See your question I have updated it.

Comment: "I tried using session variables by saving the credentials in them but still not working." shows that user is missing session_start();

Comment: I have used session_start();

Comment: Then what is the error. As your question shows that you are losing SESSION

Answer (score 0):

First start `session_start();` and pass its value `$_SESSION['var_name'];` and on other (dashboard) page check `$_SESSION['var_name']` is set or not ?

you can check this [DEMO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10097887/using-sessions-session-variables-in-a-php-login-script)