# Display only the current user's details using PHP and MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

In this part of the code, both the score table, and the profile page display everything I want, however it is displaying EVERYBODIES details like

First Name
Surname
Email
Category
Username
However, I want it so that when the user is logged in they can only see THEIR OWN details

This is score.php

```
    <?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', TRUE);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', TRUE);
require("db_connect.php");
session_start();
?>

<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">
    <link rel="icon" href="../../../../favicon.ico">

<?php
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","username","Password","Database");
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
{
echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}


$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM Score where 'Username' LIKE _['Username']");


echo "<table border='1'>
<tr>
<th>ID</th>
<th>Username</th>
<th>Score</th>
<th>Gamedate</th>
<th>QuizTitle</th>
</tr>";

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
echo "<tr>";
echo "<td>" . $row['ID'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['Username'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['Score'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['Gamedate'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['QuizTitle'] . "</td>";
echo "</tr>";
}
echo "</table>";

mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

this is profile.php

```
<?php
include_once 'db_connect.php';
?>


<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">
    <link rel="icon" href="../../../../favicon.ico">

    <title>Profile page </title>

 <?php
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","Username","password","database");
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
{
echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}

$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT `FirstName`,`Surname`,`Email`,`Username`,`Date_Creation`FROM Users ");



while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{



        echo "<br />Your <b><i>Profile</i></b> is as follows:<br />";
        echo "<b>First name:</b> ". $row['FirstName'];
        echo "<br /><b>Last name:</b> ".$row['Surname'];
        echo "<br /><b>Email:</b> ".$row['Email'];
        echo "<br /><b>Year:</b> ".$row['Username'];
        echo "<br /><b>Date created :</b> ".$row['Date_Creation'];
}


mysqli_close($con);
?>
    </main>



</html>
```

These are the errors I recieve when I try to run the page. Before I changed the select query so it picked the current user that is logged in, but it displayed everyone's information

[image: This is for the score]
[image: This is for the profile]

Comment: You need a login mechanism. With Sessions you can remember on the server side which user is currently logged in. Then you can load the data only from this user. Very basic example here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10097986/3623232

Comment: I already have a login page, where the user logs in and a home page?

Comment: You need to save the username in the session when logging in. E.g. with `$_SESSION['user'] = $username_from_form`. Do not forget the `session_start()` at the beginning of the script. Then you can check the `$_SESSION['user']` variable in your `profile.php` to get the currently logged in username.

Comment: I've just done this and nothing changed...

Comment: You're open to SQL injection - this should be addressed to ensure a safe site :)

Comment: @ThisGuyHasTwoThumbs hmmm I see it. I'm experimenting this for a project. I'll address this when I crack the code

Comment: $query = "SELECT * FROM Users WHERE `Username` = 'Username'";
$result=mysqli_query($con,$query) or die("MySQL error: " . mysqli_error($con) . "<hr>\nQuery: $query");;

while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query))
{


This is the change i've made, the error i'm now getting

Warning: mysqli_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, string given in line 91

Answer (score 0):

Single quotes in SQL are used to refer to a specific string like `'Bob'`. If you're trying to check the value of the column, don't put the column name in quotes as `'Username'`. Instead, put the column name without quotes: `where Username like`

Comment: I did this change and it showed 

Warning: mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given in /home/students/aatio001/public_html/FYP/Website/Quiz/profile.php on line 92

this is on the 
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) line

Comment: $query = "SELECT * FROM Users WHERE `Username` = 'Username'";
$result=mysqli_query($con,$query) or die("MySQL error: " . mysqli_error($con) . "<hr>\nQuery: $query");;

while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query))
{


This is the change i've made, the error i'm now getting

Warning: mysqli_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, string given in line 91

Answer (score 0):

About the errors. You can use the error handling to show what's the problem on your query. Second, you can use the ID to get the data information of the logged in user. You can save the ID of the user via session, when user logged in saved the ID then use it to your where clause.

Answer (score -1):

in your `score.php` file, on this line:

```
$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM Score where 'Username' LIKE _['Username']");
```

Look at your WHERE statement, seems to be wrong.

And in your `profile.php`, on this line:

```
$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT `FirstName`,`Surname`,`Email`,`Username`,`Date_Creation`FROM Users ");
```

You dont pass any WHERE statement. So, the problems are in your SQL, specifically on your wheres.

Comment: The intention was to use the same select and where query as the one for score in profile. I'm trying to figure out where because it seems ok

Comment: $query = "SELECT * FROM Users WHERE `Username` = 'Username'";
$result=mysqli_query($con,$query) or die("MySQL error: " . mysqli_error($con) . "<hr>\nQuery: $query");;

while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query))
{


This is the change i've made, the error i'm now getting

Warning: mysqli_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, string given in line 91

Comment: Do you have any login system? Your WHERE, in your above comment, your where condition will bring to you only the user which has the username "Username", is that right?

Comment: @IpFranz I do have a login system.. I want my WHERE condition to be that it looks at who is currently logged in and print their information?

Comment: Ok, so you have to pass to your where, the credentials (email,pass) that comes from user form, paying attention on SQL injection issues.

Comment: @IpFranz, the main goal for me is to get it all to work. I've tried copying everything from Login, but it's not working :-(