# Merge Multiple System Login Into 1

Tags: php, html, authentication

Current workplace having multiple in house system (written in PHP and HTML) hosted in our own server.

Example:

```
http://ab01/gatepass/
http://ab01/prpo/
http://ab01/efar/
http://ab01/hr/
http://ab01/finance/
```

Each system will have its independent login page with company badge id and password. (which manage by HR and IT Department.)

Being assign by superior, to merge all the logon to a Single Log On from a Consolidated Web Portal.

Example:

```
http://ab01/Login
```

So user visit the above link and log in, den all the system apps will show in listing \ tiles, then the user clicks on the link go into the system apps.

Does anyone have any reference link/guide on

- merging multiple login
- passsing multiple session

Or any helpful guide on archiving this assessment.

Comment: You could just have all those separate login page lead to that one page, no? Basically what I'm saying is re-route all traffic coming into those address to the one "single" sign in page you want. Authenticate them there, assuming that all user credentials are in one centralized database? Dunno.

Comment: Yea, all user credentials are in one centralized database.

Answer (score 0):

You can add select option drop-down with available house system in single login page, then user will choose their house system along with login detail.Then server side, validate login with house system, if validate , redirect user to respective house system.

You can store user detail with house system id in session to use.

Comment: the ideal way will be centralize login page, den user choose which system they want to go in

Comment: after login with only username&password.allow user choose system. while choose system , you can call ajax function to save chosen system id in session or database with user info to load only requested system.redirect them.And make delete session on logout.

Comment: Thanks, do you got any reference or guide on how to do that ?

Comment: It very easy to implement in PHP, reffer this (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10097887/using-sessions-session-variables-in-a-php-login-script)  or this ( https://johnmorrisonline.com/build-php-login-form-using-sessions/ )this may help you.